# Mixing raw data & model based visualization

Tags: mixed-model, data-visualization, barplot

How to handle the following request from a journal:

I've evaluated a data set using a linear mixed model (lmm). Among the evaluated factors, I was particularly interested in one, which I plotted as a bar graph (default state & modified state). After submitting the paper (and the plot) to a journal, I'm being asked to either

1. superimpose all data points I used in the lmm to the bar plot **or**
2. add for each of the two states I've plotted in the bar plot the following elements: Median values, min-values, max-values, interquartile interval etc..

Considering that I employed other factors in the lmm model to compensate for confounding patterns in the data, I'm somewhat confused by the request. IMHO, executing either on the data I put into the model might be misleading, as the visualization would now mix (confounded) raw data and (corrected) model based data.

Therefore I'm wondering, whether my reasoning is correct and how to handle the request.

Comment: Could you plot the model residuals?

Comment: I like the idea of this suggestion, plotting the model residuals to indicate how the model error spreads. However, I feel this might be seen as insufficient by the journal. The journal is from life sciences where many of the readers lack (any) statistical education. Hence many readers wouldn't know the meaning of a residual in the first place, and being unable to interpret the plot, most likely discard it. I think the original thought behind the bar plot + extensive information arises from the idea of having a t-test, where these demands seem somewhat reasonable, albeit can still be cheated.

Comment: Ideally, I'm looking for an option to display the difference between the two state's I've investigated which can be easily understood by a non-mathematical audience.

I've also attempted to merely visualize the difference (the slope estimate & it's error) but received even more backlash for that suggestion.